# ValueError: Shapes (1, 1, 512, 4) and (2, 512, 1, 1) are incompatible how to fix this error?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I don't know much English, so it may be written clumsily.
My custom code gives an error when recognizing it. I tried to change the analysis methods and file locations. But nothing helped. I'm not a super programmer, so I don't really understand what's going on deep in the code. I also don't really understand where the output image should be saved and what it will be called.
Program cod:

```
from imageai.Prediction.Custom import CustomImagePrediction
import os

execution_path = os.getcwd()

prediction = CustomImagePrediction()
prediction.setModelTypeAsSqueezeNet()
prediction.setModelPath(os.path.join(execution_path, "model_ex-065_acc-0.875000.h5"))
prediction.setJsonPath(os.path.join(execution_path, "model_class.json"))
prediction.loadModel(num_objects=4)

predictions, probabilities = prediction.predictImage(os.path.join(execution_path, "ScreenHack.jpg"), result_count=5)

for eachPrediction, eachProbability in zip(predictions, probabilities):
    print(eachPrediction , " : " , eachProbability)
```

Error text:

```
ValueError: Shapes (1, 1, 512, 4) and (2, 512, 1, 1) are incompatible
```

Comment: You *must* have the same quantity of elements on both sides of reshaping.  You are trying to cram 2048 elements into 1024.  We cannot help much, because you neglected to give us the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The dimensions of your image "ScreenHack.jpg" do not match those needed by your model, most likely. You should see the error in that line.

Answer (score 0):

Actual number of elements you can get by multiplying all values, for first it will bet 2048, for second only 1024. That's why it could not be reshaped.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly. Could you describe my problem in more detail? Error in the training file, input image or something else? What elements are the problem with?

Comment: I changed the file size (which is not very good for me) and the error disappeared, but another one appeared: OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'C:\Users\Doctor\PycharmProjects\FAKE44Type\venv\model_ex-065_acc-0.875000.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)  and I still don't know how the output image is saved. But no... After changing the directory where the h5 file was located, the same error appeared : ValueError: Shapes (1, 1, 512, 4) and (2, 512, 1, 1) are incompatible

Comment: it is hard to understand why it is different. It could be image size is not fit to that model. Or for example model wait for grayscale image and you try to pass rgb image